# List permission issue for anonymous users

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, anonymous-authentication, permissions

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using publishing portal template. I am creating a list with the default "Title" column -- Title (linked to item).

I want to make anonymous users to be able to view list content and also wants anonymous users to be able to click the Title link to see item details. But I find when I clicked Title link, I have to login in order to view item details. Any solutions to make anonymous user to be able to click and view Title link?

thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you grant permission to this list for anonymous users? Did you inherit permissions from the site or did you break inheritance and set up permission specifically for this list?

Comment: Thanks Lori, I set entire web site permission for anonymous users and inherit permission from parent site. But I find anonymous user can not see details when clicked Title link for each item.

Comment: Are the users getting the typical "Access Denied" when clicking the link or are they getting some other error?

Answer (score 2):

Another similar scenario is described here with a solution

http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2007/06/anonymous-users-cannot-access-list.html

Answer (score 1):

The Publishing Portal has the ViewFormPagesLockdown feature enabled by default.  This prevents anonymous users from accessing /_Layouts pages and AllItems.aspx pages etc.

Its not recommended but you could do this to solve your problem:

stsadm -o deactivatefeature ViewFormPagesLockdown\feature.xml -url http://yoursite

Cheers,
   James.